# Pushing to Gist remote with [name] [branch] != origin master?

Tags: github, gist

I'm having trouble trying to understand what is a good workflow for creating and maintaining a gist.  If I use default names for the remote and branch (origin master) then I can push to the gist and the revision shows up on line.  No problem.  But, if I create a new branch and successfully push that to the remote (gist) then it doesn't show up on line.  Where is it pushed to and how do I see it?

What are the specifics around gists? The git documentation states that "Every gist is a Git repository,..." but it loses interest after that and doesn't explain if they are fully implemented repos or if there are restrictions on what you can do with a gist.